# Image doesn't show in Chrome from Java HTTP server (works with Firefox)

Tags: java, html

I have an issue with Google Chrome.

I'm trying to do a Java program which stream a jpeg image on the localhost in order to show it in the web browser.

Here is the main class :

package jpegstreamer;

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class MjpegStreamer {

    private static JpegImageSource imageSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        imageSource = new Source();
        HttpServer server = null;
        try {
            server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8888), 0);
            server.createContext("/", new rootHandler());
            server.createContext("/stream", new streamHandler());
            server.setExecutor(null);
            server.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class rootHandler implements HttpHandler {

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            byte[] response = ("<!DOCTYPE html>" +
                    "<html>" +
                    "<body>" +
                    "<img src=\"./stream\"/>" +
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>").getBytes();
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length);
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response);
            os.close();
        }

    }

    static class streamHandler implements HttpHandler {
        private static final String NL = "\r\n";
        private static final String BOUNDARY = "--boundary";
        private static final String HEAD = NL + NL + BOUNDARY + NL +
                "Content-Type: image/jpeg" + NL +
                "Content-Length: ";


        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            Headers h = t.getResponseHeaders();
            h.set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, private");
            h.set("Content-Type", "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=" + BOUNDARY);
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();

            while (true) {
                //System.out.print("Outputting...");
                byte[] img = imageSource.getImage();
                os.write((HEAD + img.length + NL + NL).getBytes());
                os.write(img);
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
                //System.out.println("Done");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //os.close();
        }

    }
}
```

It works perfectly with Firefox but I got a little broken image logo in Google Chrome.
When I check the console in Chrome I've no error...

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop?  Why not write your headers and image, then close the OutputStream and return?

Comment: It's a stream video, the image change so the loop refresh the image in the localhost/stream